# How to do a loop involving dates using VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get values from a sheet with criteria involving dates. Range of date will be from Jan 1 up to Jan 31. I did some coding but honestly, not good with loops. Hopefully you can help me with these. 
So the process will be, I am filtering the data, for example, for column B, I am filtering Jan. 1, then the data from column A will be copy and paste to another sheet. After that, I am filtering again Jan. 2, copy the data from column A and paste again to another sheet, and so on...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With



    Sheets("Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/1/2019")
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("January").Select
    Range("P5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("A1").Select


    Sheets("Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/2/2019")
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("January").Select
    Range("Q5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("Q:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2
    Range("A1").Select


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you running into? Are you getting an error?

Comment: *"not good with loops"* - what loop(s)?

Comment: actually, no error so far, the thing is that right now, the way I am thinking is really bad, like just copy this part, and just change the date until I reach Jan. 31


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$1000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "**/**/****")

Comment: Start with [eliminating both `Range.Select` and working off `Selection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

Comment: is there a way to code like it will undergo from Jan. 1 to Jan. 31?? I know this is kinda noob question. but that's the farthest I can

Comment: Are you wanting to copy an entire range or just specific dates within the range?

Comment: just specific date within that range, to be exact, from Jan 1-31, 'cause from that range includes many dates from Jan to Dec

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Can also consider do so:

Sub TransferDate()

For Each cell In Worksheets("Data2").Columns(1).Cells
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        Mth = MonthName(Month(cell.Value))
        DayDate = Day(cell.Value)
        Worksheets(Mth).Cells(Rows.Count, DayDate + 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cell.Value
        Worksheets(Mth).Columns(DayDate + 15).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you just want all dates from January 2019 and aren't bothered about the order in which they appear on your `January` worksheet, you could just get rid of the loop (in the code below) and specify once: "greater than or equal to 1 January 2019" and "less than 1 February 2019". (It should be quicker than looping but the order of the output will reflect/match whatever it was on the original sheet.)
- On the other hand if you're sure you want to loop, you can try the code below. The `Application` settings can be uncommented once you know the code works correctly. (I could not test it as I don't know what your sheet looks like.)
- My filter criteria assume the hour, minute and second components of your dates are all `0`. If this is not true, you may need to adjust `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` accordingly.
- Currently, the output will be contiguous. For example, say your `Data` sheet is as below:

  - contains `28 January 2019`
  - does not contain `29 January 2019`
  - contains `30 January 2019`
- Then the output will be something like:

  - data for `28 January 2019` in some column
  - data for `30 January 2019` in the immediately next column
- In other words, no blank column will be present in the output to reflect the "missing date". If you don't have any "missing dates", this is a non-issue. But if your `January` sheet expects a blank column (for each missing date), you can move the `pasteOffset = pasteOffset + 1` line outside of the IF (after it).

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2() ' Needs renaming.

    With Application
        '.ScreenUpdating = False
        '.EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Data")

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = Worksheets("January") ' Could also determine this dynamically inside the loop, rather than hardcoding here.
    destinationSheet.Cells.Clear

    Dim includingHeaders As Range
    Set includingHeaders = sourceSheet.Range("A1:B1000")

    Dim excludingHeaders As Range
    Set excludingHeaders = includingHeaders.Offset(1).Resize(includingHeaders.Rows.Count - 1, 1)

    Dim dateIndex As Date
    For dateIndex = DateSerial(2019, 1, 1) To DateSerial(2019, 1, 31) ' Could use date literals instead (if you wanted to).
        ' Not sure if this is the best way to exactly match a date.
        includingHeaders.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(dateIndex), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(dateIndex)

        ' Range.SpecialCells method is called twice, which is inefficient.
        If includingHeaders.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
            excludingHeaders.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

            Dim pasteOffset As Long
            destinationSheet.Range("P5").Offset(0, pasteOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            pasteOffset = pasteOffset + 1 ' This is only incremented if the date exists in column B.
        End If
    Next dateIndex

    sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        '.ScreenUpdating = True
        '.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```